# How do you make CMS users' uploaded images responsive? (set max-width for all images?)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In a given CMS users upload images.  To prevent them from breaking pages I use css to specify the max image widths for different parts of the site.

Consider the following scenario.

```
<div class='a' style="width:500px;">
<img src='' width="600px" height="900px">
<img src='' width="400px" height="600px">
</div>

div.a img {
max-width:500px;
height:auto!important;
width:100%!important;
}
```

The images in div.a are responsive and no image is greater than the width of the div.  However, the images which are smaller than width 500px are stretched up to this width.

How can I have responsive images which are smaller than 500px but remain 100% of their own size (not the blanket max-width of 500px)?

The only way I can think of to solve this is to use jquery to set a max-width to every image in div.a.  If an image is wider than 500px, it's max width would be set to 500px.

I'd like to sanity check this approach and want to know how other developers are solving this problem.  Perhaps it is better to solve this problem as the editor level and have ckeditor give each image a max-width attribute?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have a read of this article detailing how the BBC do it: http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/50092458307/images

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Picture Fill with great success especially for browsers that don't support media queries. https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill